# How can I fetch the result of a SQL Query which uses a variable?

Tags: python, sqlite

Please help. I am creating a little GUI dictionary and am trying to link the interface to a database. I can enter data (word and definition) into the database correctly but I cannot seem to look up words in the database so that the appropriate definition displays in the output box on my GUI.

Module 1 (main program):

```
from tkinter import *
import libraryentrySQL
import sqlite3
import os



def click():
    entered_text = entry.get() #collect text from text entry box
    output.delete(0.0,END) #clears text box - start clearing from 0.0 (from line 0) to END (after last character)
    new_db = sqlite3.connect('dictionary.db')
    c=new_db.cursor()
    try:
        definition = c.execute("SELECT definition FROM Dictionary WHERE word=%s", (entered_text))
    except:
        definition = "No word found in dictionary, try again!"
    output.insert(END, definition) #this inserts the contents of variable 'definition' at the beginning (END) - because it was cleared before, END is the at the start

def clickentry(): #this function is run when the 2nd button (entry is pressed)
    def definition_submitted(word, definition):
        new_db = sqlite3.connect('dictionary.db')
        c=new_db.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Dictionary VALUES (?, ?)", (word, definition))
        new_db.commit()
        new_db.close()

    definition_window = libraryentrySQL.DefinitionWindow(window, definition_submitted) #this creates the object 'definition window' and passes to it 'the window variable'
                                                                                        #so that it can have a canvas
                                                                                        #and also passes the function 'definition_submitted' so that as the new word and definition are entered
                                                                                        #in the this object (second window) it can be passed into the function and the dictionary updated

window = Tk()

window.title("My Little Dictionary")

#Create the Label
Label(window, text="Enter the word you want defining:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

#create entry box
entry=Entry(window, width=20, bg="light green")
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

#create submit button
Button(window, text="Submit", width=5, command=click).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

#create second label
Label(window, text="\nDefinition").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

#create text box
output=Text(window, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background="light green")
output.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

#create submit button to open enter new definition window
Button(window, text="Enter a New Definition", width=20, command=clickentry).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)


#Create the Dictionary.db if not already present
if not os.path.isfile("dictionary.db"):
    new_db = sqlite3.connect('dictionary.db')
    c=new_db.cursor()

    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Dictionary
    (word text,
    definition text)''')

    c.execute('''INSERT INTO Dictionary VALUES
    ('Algorithm', 'Step by step instructions to complete a task')''')

    new_db.commit()
    new_db.close()

window.mainloop()
```

module 2 (enter word and definition window):

```
from tkinter import *

class DefinitionWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, root, click_callback):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, root)
        self.click_callback = click_callback
        self.title("Library entry")

        #Create the Label
        Label(self, text="Enter the word you want to add:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        #create entry box
        self.word_entry=Entry(self, width=20, bg="light green")
        self.word_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

        #create second label
        Label(self, text="\nDefinition").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

        #create entry box
        self.definition_entry = Entry(self, width=50, bg="light green")
        self.definition_entry.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

        #create submit button
        Button(self, text="Submit", width=5, command=self.clicked).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

    def clicked(self):
        self.click_callback(self.word_entry.get(), self.definition_entry.get()) #when this function is called (on submit button click) it takes the entered
                                                                                #word and definition and assigns it to click_callback, which is an attribute of DefinitionWindow??
        self.destroy() #after the word and definition are added to the call_back variable, the frame containing this instance of definition window is closed
```

What am I doing wrong? I know it is the "SELECT" SQL command which is not correct. Any help would be gratefully received. Thanks

Comment: May I ask, why was this question marked down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how SQL queries in Python work.

The `execute` method returns not a value but a cursor.
When nothing was found, no exception is raised, and the cursor is just empty.

Handling all exceptions blindy in the `except` block will hide any programming errors.

Furthermore, the parameters marker is not `%s` but `?`.

Finally, a Python tuple with a single value must include a comma to differentiate it from a single expression:

```
c = new_db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT definition FROM Dictionary WHERE word = ?", (entered_text,))
for row in c:
    definition = row[0]
    break
else:
    definition = "No word found in dictionary, try again!"
output.insert(END, definition)
```

Comment: Thank you, you have been a great help.